# How can I test for a player wearing specific armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I test for a player that is wearing an iron helmet named "test1" and an iron chestplate named "test2" in Minecraft Version 1.12?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 8):

Although you can't set player data with commands, you can test for it, in your example it's like this:

```
/execute as @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:iron_helmet",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"test1\"}"}}},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"test2\"}"}}}]}] run <command>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the correct syntax be `/execute as @p[nbt={...}]`, not `/execute as @p{...}`

Comment: @pppery That is correct. I'm suprised that four people upvoted a non-functioning command. It's fixed now.

Comment: The original answer functioned and attracted 3 upvotes. The error was introduced with the update to 1.13.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that adds a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags_commands) to any player wearing both of those custom items.  This tag can then be used to target only those players with other commands.  Commands are for 1.12.2.

---

Use 2 command blocks in a chain.

The first command block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove Wearing
```

The second command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add Wearing {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:iron_helmet",tag:{display:{Name:test1}}},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",tag:{display:{Name:test2}}}]}
```

Now you can use this tag to target the players who are currently wearing the named armor.  The [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) would be:

```
@a[tag=Wearing]
```